# Is it possible to enforce inclusion of a string from a static library into any executable that links it?

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking

I'd like to put a version string into statically linked library and enforce that it gets included in the image of any executable that links it, so I can check the image (e.g. with `strings`) and see the version string.

Is this possible with standard C and/or gcc and without the need to specially adjust the linking options of the executable? (Because adjusting the linking of executables which use those static libraries is something that is easy to forget / tedious to maintain...)

It seems I've managed to achieve this in C++ with

```
extern char const * that_version_string;
static char const * const foo_that_version_string = that_version_string;
```

in the libraries' header file.
But C won't compile this: "non-const initializer" or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean a statically linked library?  Because if so, the linked exe will include the library code, and hence your library version string will already be in the file.

Comment: @Peter M: Yes, statically linked. The linked exe will only contain referenced / used objects from the library, not all objects. I don't want to change that behavior for any objects but this version string. E.g. the exe should still contain only the needed functions from the library.

Comment: Why don't you simply add to the library `const char* Version() {return "your_version_str";}`? The (constant) string will reside in the RO data section of the library object code, and the function will return a pointer to that string whenever it is called.

Comment: @barak manos: because this requires explicit collaboration on the side of the executable, which adds maintenance overhead and is error-prone. I'd like to force the inclusion implicitly just through the librarys' header file. Something that would be like `#pragma used that_version_string` - and the linker would always include the string in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the library `foo` has an initialization function `fooInit` that *must* be called in order to use the library. Then, in that function, put the following code.

```
char const * that_version_string = "Foo 1.0";
char const * this_version_string;

void fooInit( void )
{
    this_version_string = that_version_string;

    // more initialization code ...
}
```

Be sure to check the assembly code when compiling the library to verify that the compiler didn't optimize out the assignment. It shouldn't, since `this_version_string` is a global that could potentially be used elsewhere.

Comment: This brings me to another idea that could work in some projects: have a `#define USED_STATIC_LIBRARIES` that each included library header can extend and that the main executable can use in a `print_full_version()` function ... This would also work for header-only libraries. I'm still looking for a solution that wouldn't need explicit collaboration on the side of the executable - and that would work without a fooInit()-like function.

Comment: @Zrin Yup, a `print_full_version()` function in the main executable would definitely work. I think there would have to be some way to call the function, e.g. a `-v` option, or the function and everything it references could be optimized out.